# What is this METRIC ATTRIBUTE in crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-answers

I am working on an android app. I am adding custom atrributes which are integers to a crashlytics custom event. In crashlytics dashboard it is showing me some metric attribute which I don't know. For string it is events count.

code:

```
 Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Specific screen")
          .putCustomAttribute("userid", 1));
```

[image]

Comment: "it is showing me some metric attribute which I don't know" can you explain a little more what you mean here?

Comment: i added image check it,here userid is integer

Comment: Got it. We try to infer the data type. Since the ID is set to a number we're showing charts for numerical data sets. If you make it a string you should be all set.